# CGContextShowTextAtPoint has fixed size even during different iteration?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am drawing some text in my custom view with the following code:

```
- (void)drawProgramDescription:(CGContextRef) context {
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    // get string from dataSource
    NSString *programDescription = [self.dataSource giveDescriptionOfProgram:self];
    // convert string to a C string
    const char *programDescriptionCString = [programDescription 
                                             cStringUsingEncoding:kCGEncodingMacRoman];
    CGContextSelectFont(context, "Helvetica", 1, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
    // draw it
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 20, 20, programDescriptionCString, 
                                              sizeof(programDescriptionCString) + 1);
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```

This method is called in my `drawRect` method so that the text gets displayed on my custom view.

However, the problem is that it seems the size of the string put into the `CGContextShowTextAtPoint` is fixed even my `drawRect` is in a different iteration already.

So for example, if the text shown first time is:

```
X*X
```

And at the second time drawRect is called it should draw the text

```
sin(X)
```

It will not display the text fully, and instead the text is cut at

```
sin(
```

Which still has the original size from the first iteration of drawRect.

Is this a feature of `CGContextShowTextAtPoint`? Or am I missing something?

Thank you!

Comment: May one ask, why are you not using the NSString drawing methods? A C string is not an NSString, and the ways of drawing a C string are very crude.

Comment: @matt Because `CGContextShowTextAtPoint()` requires a C string.

Comment: Right, but `drawAtPoint` and `drawInRect` do not, and they do a better job of drawing the string. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: And in iOS 6, NSAttributedString has parallel methods, so you can actually draw styled text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be happier escaping from `CGContextShowTextAtPoint`. It is way too restricted. Instead, use the methods documented in the [NSString UIKit Additions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html).

They draw real NSStrings. They draw into the current context. And they know much more about strings, encodings, fonts, bounding rectangles, etc.

In iOS 6 there are even parallel NSAttributedString methods.

Comment: that looks like a better option! Thanks for letting me know about this!

Answer (score 2):

Because [pointers are not arrays](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html).

```
sizeof(programDescriptionCString)
```

yields the size of a pointer, which is apparently 4 bytes. Use `strlen()` instead (and grab an introductory C tutorial).

Comment: Oh that's right! I already learned C actually. How did I forget that! Thank you so much!